# Undefined reference to main when using Real-Time For the Masses

Tags: rust, embedded, cortex-m, stm32f4discovery

I'm trying to write a multi-threaded bare-metal application for the STM32F4Discovery using the Real-Time For the Masses (RTFM) [crate](https://docs.rs/crate/cortex-m-rtfm/0.3.4). I've frankensteined together a minimal application from an [example](https://github.com/rust-embedded/discovery/tree/master/src/05-led-roulette) for the STM32F3Discovery board and [this example](http://blog.japaric.io/rtfm-v2/#hello-world):

```
#![deny(unsafe_code)]
#![no_main]
#![no_std]

extern crate cortex_m;
extern crate cortex_m_rtfm as rtfm;
extern crate cortex_m_semihosting;
extern crate panic_semihosting;
extern crate stm32f4;

use stm32f4::stm32f407;

use rtfm::app;

app! {
    device: stm32f407,
}

fn init(_p: init::Peripherals) {
}

fn idle() -> ! {
    loop {
        rtfm::wfi();
    }
}
```

I can get it to compile but linking with rust-lld fails with

```
= note: rust-lld: error: undefined symbol: main
```

I am confused because when I run `cargo expand` I do get a main function:

```
fn main() {
    #![allow(path_statements)]
    let init: fn(init::Peripherals) = init;
    rtfm::atomic(unsafe { &mut rtfm::Threshold::new(0) },
                 |_t|
                     unsafe {
                         let _late_resources =
                             init(init::Peripherals{core:
                                                        ::stm32f407::CorePeripherals::steal(),
                                                    device:
                                                        ::stm32f407::Peripherals::steal(),});
                     });
    let idle: fn() -> ! = idle;
    idle();
}
```

I'm new to Rust (in fact I was hoping to learn the language with this project)  and have no idea where the error might be located.

Comment: But you put `#![no_main]` in your code

Comment: I just copied that from the example. If I remove the `#![no_main]` the compiler complains that the `start` `lang_item` is missing.

Comment: What exemple, one link you provided don't use no_main and the other use `use aux5::entry;

#[entry]`

Comment: [This](https://github.com/rust-embedded/discovery/blob/master/src/05-led-roulette/src/main.rs) main has it. Anyway, like I said, if I remove it, I get the missing `start` `lang_item` error and the way I understood it, `app!` should expand to a working main.
I'm sorry if this is all obvious stuff. To me all this macro magic is pretty confusing right now.

Comment: But like I said, this main use a macro [`entry`](https://rust-embedded.github.io/cortex-m-rt/0.6.1/cortex_m_rt_macros/fn.entry.html) you think is here for nothing ?

Comment: I thought `app!` would take care of it. After all the [example](http://blog.japaric.io/rtfm-v2/#hello-world) I referenced doesn't seem to need it either.

Comment: But this one don't use no_main... you can't mix example take only few line and expect thing work

Comment: I know. But since I don't get what isn't working, I asked the question here. So I guess you're telling me that my problem really is that missing `start` `lang_item`.

Comment: I never said that, i already answered your question, I don't know how to use your crate, I only know the general answer.

Comment: Alright, thanks. I'll probably delete this question then and ask about the `lang_item`.

Comment: You should not delete question, just create a new one but I don't think you should, just [edit] your actual question to improve it.

Answer (score 0):

As you ask the compiler to not insert `main`, there is no main symbol in your program.

Rust uses symbol mangling so your `main` function doesn't have a symbol named `main`.

The answer depends on your contextm but generally this should do it:

```
#[no_mangle] // ensure that this symbol is called `main` in the output
pub extern fn main(argc: i32, argv: *const *const u8) -> i32 {

}
```

All additional information can be found [here](https://doc.rust-lang.org/1.1.0/book/no-stdlib.html)