# Missing `start` lang_item when using Real-Time For the Masses

Tags: rust, embedded, cortex-m, stm32f4discovery

I'm trying to write a multi-threaded bare-metal application for the STM32F4Discovery using the Real-Time For the Masses (RTFM) [crate](https://docs.rs/crate/cortex-m-rtfm/0.3.4). I've frankensteined together a minimal application from an [example](https://github.com/rust-embedded/discovery/tree/master/src/05-led-roulette) for the STM32F3Discovery board and [this example](http://blog.japaric.io/rtfm-v2/#hello-world):

```
#![no_std]

extern crate cortex_m;
extern crate cortex_m_rtfm as rtfm;
extern crate cortex_m_semihosting;
extern crate panic_semihosting;
extern crate stm32f4;

use stm32f4::stm32f407;

use rtfm::app;

app! {
    device: stm32f407,
}

fn init(_p: init::Peripherals) {
}

fn idle() -> ! {
    loop {
        rtfm::wfi();
    }
}
```

Compilation fails with

```
error: requires `start` lang_item
```

I'm new to Rust (in fact I was hoping to learn the language with this project) and have no idea where the error might be located. Is it just that the `app!` macro is broken or am I missing something?

Comment: I'm thoroughly unfamiliar with what you're trying to do, but in the linked example the first line of code starts with `#![feature(proc_macro)] // <- IMPORTANT! Feature gate for procedural macros`, but you're missing it. Could that be it?

Comment: A good tutorial is https://os.phil-opp.com/freestanding-rust-binary/

Comment: @orlp No that's just some remnant from before procedural macros became stable. I suppose all these examples being a bit dated is part of the problem.

Comment: @hellow thank you. I'm pretty sure now that the `app!` macro is broken - at least for current nightly toolchains - as it should provide the program's entry point.

Comment: With this question you are basically on the wrong track, IMHO you need `#[no_main]`, and this error won't occur. You need a vector table with a reset vector, which points to a reset handler function. This function needs to set up global variables (`bss` and `data` sections) and then call `main`. The examples you copied together hide part of this behind some macro magic, and part of it is in the `cortex-m*` crates.

Comment: I ran into different problems combining `#[no_main]` with RTFM (see https://stackoverflow.com/a/52427009/3749401). And the way I understand it RTFM and `app!` should take care of initialization. I suppose I'll have to wait for an update to RTFM if I want to use the macro.

Answer (score 1):

I've found a workaround in RTFM's [issues on GitHub](https://github.com/japaric/cortex-m-rtfm/issues/88) that allows to compile the code above:

1. import `cortex-m-rt` and its `entry` macro

   ```
   #[macro_use(entry)]
   extern crate cortex_m_rt as rt;
   ```
2. add `#![no_main]` to the head of the source
3. wrap the main function using the `entry` macro:

   ```
   #[entry]
   fn entry_wrap() -> ! {
       main();
       loop {}
   }
   ```

I haven't tested this yet but it compiles without problems.

Comment: I tell you that long ago: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52425667/undefined-reference-to-main-when-using-real-time-for-the-masses/52427009#comment91798519_52425667 & https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52425667/undefined-reference-to-main-when-using-real-time-for-the-masses/52427009#comment91800626_52425667

Comment: You failed to get your point across. I'm a beginner at Rust and your passive-aggressive question didn't help me at atll.

Comment: Well, sorry about that, didn't want to be agressif just make you think.

Comment: Alright, no hard feelings. I suppose a short explanation or a link to a resource explaining the interplay of `entry`, `#[no_main]` and how to use all that to solve my problem would have been more helpful.